# Min-Heap in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, heap-sort

As part of my study on fundamentals, I have implemented the following code in JavaScript for a `MinHeap` data structure.

Please have a look and I look forward to your feedback for any improvements.

```js
const swap = require('../swap');

function Heap(){
  this.heap = [];
}

Heap.prototype.getParent = function(index){
  return (index-1)/2;
}

Heap.prototype.getLeft = function(index){
  return (2*index)+1;
}

Heap.prototype.getRight = function(index){
  return (2*index)+2;
}

//inserts a new value to the min-heap
Heap.prototype.insert = function(value){
  this.heap.push(value);
  this.heapifyUp(this.heap.length-1);
  return;
}

//deletes any node at given index
Heap.prototype.delete = function(index){
  if(index === 0){
    this.heap[0] = this.heap[this.heap.length-1];
    this.heap.splice(this.heap.length-1, 1);
    this.heapifyDown(0);
    return;
  }

  this.heap[index] = this.heap[this.heap.length-1];
  this.heap.splice(this.heap.length-1, 1);
  var parent = this.getParent(index);
  (this.heap[index]<this.heap[parent])? this.heapifyUp(index) : this.heapifyDown(index);
  return;
}

//extracts min value and recalibrates minheap
Heap.prototype.extractMin = function(){
  var temp = this.heap[0];

  swap(this.heap, 0, (this.heap.length-1));
  this.heap.slice((this.heap.length-1), 1);
  this.heapifyDown(0);

  return temp;
}

//decreases the value of node at given index by given value
Heap.prototype.decrease = function(index, value){

  if((this.heap[index]-value)<0) return false;

  this.heap[index] = this.heap[index]-value;
  (index === 0) ? this.heapifyDown(0) : this.heapifyUp(index);
  return;
}


Heap.prototype.heapifyUp = function(index){

  var parent = this.getParent(index);

  while(parent>=0 && this.heap[parent]>this.heap[index]){
    swap(this.heap, parent, index);
    index = parent;
    parent = this.getParent(index);
  }

}

Heap.prototype.heapifyDown = function(index){

  var left = this.getLeft(index);
  var right = this.getRight(index);

  while(this.heap[index]>this.heap[left] || this.heap[index]>this.heap[right]){
    if(this.heap[index]>this.heap[left]){
      swap(this.heap, left, index);
      index = left;
      left = this.getLeft(index);
    }
    if(this.heap[index]>this.heap[right]){
      swap(this.heap, right, index);
      index = right;
      right = this.getLeft(index);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: bug in `delete(0)`: duplicates the item that is last in the array. You're missing the `splice` to shorten the array.

Comment: bug in `decrease()` it allows negative values, which cause the item to be increased in value, whic breaks up the heap property

Comment: I had to roll back your edit. You're not allowed to edit the code after you initially post, per the rules of your site. If you want the new code reviewed, post a new question, and post links between each of them.

Comment: @Snowbody Just keep the edit. Broken code is off-topic anyway and https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5688/is-it-okay-to-modify-code-in-a-post-if-weve-discovered-a-bug-before-receiving/5690#5690 suggests that editing before the first answer is still acceptable

Comment: Okay @le_m the fixed version is back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code seems good to me. You have one bug and some unnecessary code.

- First of all, it's not clear what types of values can be stored in the heap. It looks like it's supposed to be positive numbers, but the only place you check for this is in the decrease-key function. But there's actually not anything stopping callers from attempting to store strings, negative numbers, classes, etc. This will lead to bizarre behavior. I think you need to validate the input and make sure only the right type of data is going in.
- It's not necessary to end your functions with `return`
- The line

  > ```
  > (this.heap[index]<this.heap[parent])? this.heapifyUp(index) : this.heapifyDown(index);
  > ```

  should be written as a normal `if`, not a ternary.
- This line

  > ```
  > this.heap.slice((this.heap.length-1), 1);
  > ```

  is repeated several times; perhaps it should be brought into its own helper method with an explanatory name (suggest `deleteLastElement()`).
- In `extractMin()`, this line:

  > ```
  > swap(this.heap, 0, (this.heap.length-1));
  > ```

  performs unnecessary work. The last element is about to be deleted, so you don't need to put anything there. Just say

  ```
  this.heap[0]=this.heap[this.heap.length-1]`
  ```
- A conceptual problem is that you only allow accessing nodes by index. How is someone using your code supposed to know what the index is? An item could move around the heap a lot due to inserts and removals and heapify calls. This applies to `decrease()` and `delete()`
- `heapifyDown()` has a bug. Consider the heap represented by `[4,6,5,7]` and what happens if you `extractMin()`.
- `decreaseKey()` has a bug, but I'm not going to find this one for you.

Comment: Thanks @Snowbody! I'll correct these issues and post as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

One other aspect I noticed is that the `swap` inclusion line uses the [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) statement. You could  use `const` and [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) where appropriate. For example, in the method `delete()`, this line:

> ```
> var parent = this.getParent(index);
> ```

Could use `const`, since there appears to be no re-assignment.

```
const parent = this.getParent(index);
```